# copy contents of cvs diff in a file

Tags: linux, unix, cvs

Can I copy results of a cvs diff in a file,
For example I want to do something like

```
cp cvs diff /test/diff.txt
```

I dont know if I can do something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29) to save the output of any command to a file. Try this:

```
cvs diff > /test/diff.txt
```